# calling an object for different user defined function def

Tags: python-3.x

i have been trying to call the object variable 'file1' which has the filepath from askfileopen() and want to perform some different operations on the file with different buttons but its not working

i have tried to make file1 as global but dosent work as askopen suddenly opens if i run the code,i want to call file1 which has the imported file path from mfileopen to mfile0

```
def mfileopen():
   file1 = fdialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("csv files", "*.csv"), 
                                          ("xlsx files", "*.xlsx")])


def mfile0(): 
   df = pd.read_csv(file1)
   list(df.columns)
   return df.columns
```

Comment: Variable `file1` is known only in th context of function `mfileopen`. You should pass it from that function to any other function which relies on it.

Comment: Try reading a bit about [scopes in python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python). Using the same name for a variable in different scopes doesn't ensure it is actually the same object

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning anything. So after you leave the function you end the scope and garbage collect everything (get rid of it). You also haven't posted the code you used to run the two functions. You could try something like:

```
def mfileopen():

    return fdialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("csv files",".csv"),("xlsx 
    files",".xlsx")])

def mfile0(): 
    file1 = mfileopen()
    df = pd.read_csv(file1) 
    list(df.columns)  # do something here (e.g. print or return)
```

Comment: not working first mfileopen select the file and in mfile0 when i click show columns then file selection window pops up again i dont want to select same file again and again

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing the code you use for these function calls. In the above example you would never directly call mfileopen(). You would just use mfile0().